# How do I see how much ether was sent to a contract when it was called?

Tags: contract-development

I want to implement a contract where users are required to deposit a certain amount of money in order to participate. If the user doesn't send enough money, I simply want to send it back to them and not include them in the protocol. How do I see how many eth `msg.sender` sent to the contract when they called it? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `msg.value`.

You can read more [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties).